# Is there a future proof way to add properties to native browser objects given "use strict" behavior?

Tags: javascript, html

I noticed recently that when `"use strict";` mode is on in browsers many properties on native objects become unsettable.

For example

```
function() {
  "use strict";
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.offsetLeft = 0;  
}();
```

*Ignore the fact that setting `offsetLeft` is stupid. That's not the point.*

If you run this in Chrome or Firefox you'll get an error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property offsetLeft of #<HTMLElement> which has only
a getter(…)
```

Remove the `"use strict";` and the error goes away.

So here's the problem. Let's change `offsetLeft` to something I might use in my own code

```
function createElementAndAssociateData(data) {
  "use strict";
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.userdata = data;  
};
```

This works great, except 2 years from a new HTML5 spec comes out and decides that all HTMLElements have `userdata` attribute that's read only. Suddenly my code breaks everywhere I used `"use strict";`.

Is this a time bomb waiting to happen as more and more properties are added to native HTML5 objects?

Is there a safe way to use `"use strict";` and add custom properties to native HTML5 objects or should adding any kind of property to a native browser object never be done?

Note: I don't believe obfusticating the property names is an acceptable solution. Sure I could change `userdata` to `mycompanyname_myappname_userdata` but that's kind of beside the point. Is there some other solution or is adding custom properties to native HTML5 objects in strict mode an anti-pattern?

Comment: Note the problem is not `"use strict"`. Attempting to set a property with a getter but no setter throws in strict mode, but is ignored in non-strict mode. Both behaviors may be undesired. The real problem is that you modify (add properties to) an object you don't own, and that's dangerous.

Comment: To be honest I would never do this. But I've see it used quite often. For example that pattern is all over [learningwebgl.com](http://learningwebgl.com). I also ran into once with a polyfill. It was trying to emulate something and one day suddenly broke after a browser update or because a use strict was added somewhere upstream in a build process.

Comment: The answer is don't extend the DOM with random properties. This issue has been around since scripting for browsers, see Kangax's [*What's wrong with extending the DOM*](http://perfectionkills.com/whats-wrong-with-extending-the-dom/). Just don't do it. While the article focuses on extending prototypes (which host objects aren't required to have), it applies in general.

Comment: *"Sure I could change userdata to mycompanyname_myappname_userdata but that's kind of beside the point"* I don't see how that's beside the point. Choosing a name that they (people defining new standard DOM properties) won't use surely solves the problem you've described? That's what jQuery does.

Comment: Why not use just _one_ namespaced property like `mycompanyname_myappname_userdata` and set it to an object on which you set your remaining properties (using sane names)?

Comment: Using an obfusticated name is a good *get it done* solution. My question is rather is there better non-hacky solution. If you're on a big team one team member makes `mycompany_myappname_userdata.width` and some guy on another team also does that and you'll still have a clash. So now you end up needing to make obscure naming rules and hope people follow them. If there is a better solution why not choose it? If there isn't a better solution than sure I'd consider obfusticated names.

Answer (score 21):

**Yes: ES6 symbols**

The problem with properties is that their name is a string. Then, two different codes may choose to use the same name for different purposes, and the result may be disastrous.

To solve this problem, ECMAScript 6 introduces a new type: [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

You can use it like this:

```js
var s1 = Symbol("My property");
object[s1] = "Some data 1";
object[s1]; // "Some data 1"
```

Then, even if some other code decides to use a symbol with the same description, there won't be any collision:

```js
var s2 = Symbol("My property"); // Same description :S
object[s2] = "Some data 2";
object[s2]; // "Some data 2"
object[s1]; // "Some data 1" -- No problem :)
```

Comment: This answer is interesting but it requires quite a bit of code restructuring. The symbol reference needs to be available to any piece of code that wants to access the property. That's not true with custom properties or with dataset. Not saying that's bad just that if you want some external code to be able to read the property you have to either expose a getter or expose the symbol.

Comment: @gman External code can get the symbols with `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols`. There is also a global symbol registry where you can store symbols by name, via `Symbol.for` and `Symbol.keyFor`

Comment: So you're suggesting I should call `Object.getOwnPropertiesSymbols` and then iterate through them to find "My property" and if there are 2 of them then???

Comment: @gman Then you can check the value, or use the global symbol registry.

Comment: That's a long long way from must `someObject.myProperty`.  And you mentioned there can be 2 of them so how would I distinguish between both? My comment above was not meant to dis this solution, only to point out it requires passing the symbol around or making a getter to be useful in the same way that `someObject.myProperty` is useful. That's not bad just different. There are certainly benefits, no collisions. But it requires a pretty big restructuring to apps that were previously using custom properties

Answer (score 8):

The intended way of adding custom properties is with [`HTMLElement.dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.dataset.yourCustomProperty = 'some data';
div; // <div data-your-custom-property="some data">
div.dataset.yourCustomProperty; // "some data"
```

This reflects the custom [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes).

Note that `.dataset.camelCase` reflects `data-camel-case` and the other way round.

Comment: Custom data attributes are great, but have the limitation that can only store strings.

Comment: @Oriol You can always use JSON strings with several other types and parse them.

Comment: Parsing strings and stringifying objects is nice, but has some performance implication, so you can't always go with this solution.

Comment: @alexanderfarkas yes, and it looses object identity and other features.

Answer (score 8):

In general your code would also break if you would remove `"use strict";`, because your property has not the value, that you wanted it to have.

In general extending native objects is a not so good idea.

Here are some options:

1. Use one name spaced key for example `_myframeworkElemID`, that won't be speced.
2. Create a dynamic key (similar to 1.): 
   jQuery for example creates a key like this: `$.expando = 'jQuery' + Date.now();`
3. Use jQuery.data or implement a similar solution.
4. modern ways

   a) Symbols (covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555035/is-there-a-future-proof-way-to-add-properties-to-native-browser-objects-given-u#answer-32555084))

   b) WeakMap:

```
window.elementData = new WeakMap();

//later than
//set data
elementData.set(element, data)

//get data
elementData.get(element);
```

---

All this said. From my viewpoint the **currently best way to do it** looks like this:

```
var expando = window.Symbol && Symbol() || '_myId' + Date.now();

//set data
element[expando] = data;

//get data
var data = element[expando];
```

This way you use the ES6 Symbol feature in browsers that support it and in legacy browsers you get a unique string, that will never be specified.

You can of course also write a helper, that returns the symbol.

Comment: jQuery.data? Is this different from `obj.dataset` from the answer of Xufox?

Comment: Yes, it is different. A $.data set will never write a `data-*` atttribute. On first set/get jQuery will parse data-* attributes. jQuery then extends this element with an id and stores the object in to a cache. Every get/set accesss is then only to this cached data, not the data- attributes. As explained this is done by extending every element with a new key. You can check this by executing jQuery.expando in your console. Even for this simple key, jQuery decided not to use the data-* attributes for perf reasons. Although it would be possible (data-jquery123789242="uuid-99").